# How do folks normally handle logging an until loop without generating too much logging on the console/or ansible main log?

Tags: ansible

My goal is to use ansible until loops for retries without:

- masking details about the failures
- overwhelming logs by logging everything at a -vvv level

According to the [2.3.0 docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops), -vv will provide details about each loop iteration but this is not 100% accurate.  It does show status but not the actual failure details

```
TASK [Ansible Shows data on Each Attempt] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Ansible Shows data on Each Attempt (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Ansible Shows data on Each Attempt (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Ansible Shows data on Each Attempt (1 retries left).
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "attempts": 3,
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "rc": 1
}
```

When I run an ansible with `-vvv` I get the detailed information per iteration but I also get a bunch of details about ssh which is more verbose than I'd like.

```
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask...
```

### Playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Ansible Shows data on Each Attempt
    command: "date; ls -l doesNotExist"
    become: yes
    register: tresult
    until: tresult.rc == 0
    retries: 3
    delay: 1
```

### Options

- run with -vvv and deal with complex logs
- send output an iteration file and display them only on failure or collect them on failure
- something nicer that you already do?

Comment: You should probably have a look at [callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) because IMO it looks like a case where you will have to [implement your own](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins)

Comment: Yeah, that's an option.  I do already have my own.  I have the logs transform into junit tests so jenkins can make them more easily understood.  I guess I could slip it into that.  That's probably the best approach.  Thanks @Zeitounator

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a bang without a blast, there is a trick. It's a bit verbose to write, but it generates a really good output.

```
- block:
   - module:
       args: to_module
  rescue:
   - module:
       args: the_same_args_to_the_same_module
     retries: ..
     until: etc
```

It produces a very visual output without causing any bad effects for the playbook:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => ...
ok: [localhost] => ...

PLAY RECAP *****************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0
```

Comment: oooh. that holds promise.  I'll need to play around with the rescue option.  Thanks for that.  The key will be if I can see the details for each iteration of the loop